# Is using Dev/Test RDS is bad idea for your project over Production RDS?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am a student. I am using AWS free tier account. I don't have money to pay for the resources. I have developed an application for the society. I don't want my website should face any downtime in production just because of the free service provided by Amazon.SO, can I go for the Dev/Test RDS for my production application?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The basic different between a Dev/Test configuration for Amazon RDS and a Production configuration is that the Production configuration has **Multi-AZ** activated. This means that there is a secondary database provisioned in case of failure of the primary database or the Availability Zone in which the database is running.

Such failures are rare and given that you are cost-conscious and you are not providing a commercial-grade application, using the Dev/Test configuration would be acceptable.

Please note that the intention of the [AWS Free Tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/) is *"to gain free, hands-on experience with the AWS platform, products, and services"*. It is not intended as a way to host applications for free.